# Role of mode in bottleneck function in unet network

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have come across the script that belongs to a person in kaggle. The snippet is given below.

```
 def bottleneck(x,filters_bottleneck,mode='cascade', depth=6,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'):
   dilated_layers = []
   if mode == 'cascade':
      for i in range(depth):
        x = Conv2D(filters_bottleneck,kernel_size,activation=activation,padding='same',dilation_rate=2**i)(x)
        dilated_layers.append(x)
      return add(dilated_layers)
  elif mode == 'parallel':
     for i in range(depth):
       dilated_layers.append(Conv2D(filters_bottleneck,kernel_size,
                            activation=activation,padding='same',dilation_rate=2**i)(x))
       return add(dilated_layers)
```

To understand what the function `bottleneck` does, A pictorial explanation is given below. The highlighted portion is the bottleneck. This part of the network is between the contracting and expanding paths.

[image]

The function `bottleneck` accepts a parameter `mode`. Am confused with the parameter `mode`. Is the parameter `mode` part of the vocabulary of deep learning, if so, can you help me by providing additional resources to understand. And the same applies to the `cascade` in mode parameter too.

Answer (score 1):

That `mode` parameter is simply referring to *how* (what way) the bottleneck should be, what type of bottleneck to use.

There is nothing fancy to it. There is at least one usage in statistics of mode that I know of, as a way to describe some distributions, but this doesn't have anything to do with it.

As to the difference between *cascade* and *parallel*, in the former the layers pass the input to each other (like in the diagram), while in the latter the layers operate on the same input.

In general, *cascade* refers to the application of operations sequentially (e.g. in a cascade classifier). *Parallel* means that operations are performed independently and could, theoretically, be ran simultaneously (think about parallel operations for threads). Here, those layers are parallel since they all operate on the same input, and their output is then collected by subsequent layers.